# How to fill a row with information from another row

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a huge data set with a similar structure to this one:

```
FMID <- c(101,101,102,102,103,103,104,104)
IID <- c("101A","101B", "102A", "102B", "103A", "103B","104A", "1034")
PC1 <- c(2,NA,3,4,NA,4,NA,3)
ZY <- c(1,1,1,1,3,3,1,1)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(FMID,IID, PC1, ZY))
```

And I need to duplicate some values in the variable PC1

So, for those cases with the same FMID and ZY==1 (If one of them , A or B, has an NA) I want to fill the NA using information from the other case with the same FMID.

Here the expected result:

```
FMID <- c(101,101,102,102,103,103)
IID <- c("101A","101B", "102A", "102B", "103A", "103B","104A", "1034")
PC1 <- c(2,2,3,4,NA,4,3,3)
ZY <- c(1,1,1,1,3,3,1,1)

df_Expected <- as.data.frame(cbind(FMID,IID, PC1, ZY))
```

I have tried with ifelse but I cannot make it work. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is as shown below:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(FMID) %>%
    mutate(na_loc = is.na(PC1)& ZY !=1) %>%
    fill(PC1, .direction = 'downup') %>%
    mutate(PC1 = `is.na<-`(PC1, na_loc), na_loc = NULL)

# A tibble: 8 × 4
# Groups:   FMID [4]
  FMID  IID   PC1   ZY   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 101   101A  2     1    
2 101   101B  2     1    
3 102   102A  3     1    
4 102   102B  4     1    
5 103   103A  NA    3    
6 103   103B  4     3    
7 104   104A  3     1    
8 104   1034  3     1
```

Comment: That is amazing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**data.table**

```r
FMID <- c(101,101,102,102,103,103)
IID <- c("101A","101B", "102A", "102B", "103A", "103B")
PC1 <- c(2,NA,3,4,NA,4)
ZY <- c(1,1,1,1,3,3)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(FMID,IID, PC1, ZY))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ZY == 1, PC1 := zoo::na.locf(PC1), by = FMID][]
#>    FMID  IID  PC1 ZY
#> 1:  101 101A    2  1
#> 2:  101 101B    2  1
#> 3:  102 102A    3  1
#> 4:  102 102B    4  1
#> 5:  103 103A <NA>  3
#> 6:  103 103B    4  3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` by group to replace `NA`s in `PC1` by the non-NA value from the same `FMID` group, only when `ZY` is 1.

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(PC1 = replace(PC1, is.na(PC1) & ZY == 1, na.omit(PC1)), .by = FMID)

#   FMID  IID  PC1 ZY
# 1  101 101A    2  1
# 2  101 101B    2  1
# 3  102 102A    3  1
# 4  102 102B    4  1
# 5  103 103A <NA>  3
# 6  103 103B    4  3
```

Comment: This will also fill `ZY != 1`. Also notice that OP could have `B`with a value and `A` with no value and you would have to fill upwards. ie *(If one of them , A or B, has an NA) I want to fill the NA using information from the other case with the same FMID.* The solution is incomplete

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I have added a new case to show that the NA value could also be the first one. So that approach is not valid.

Comment: Good points @Onyambu. I edited accordingly

Comment: @JuanJMV see my edited answer. Does that work?